# How is this parseable to Java Objects (JSON)

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

From the server API I get the following output:

```
{
"1": {
"link": "http://www.hfk-bremen.de/t/meisterkurse/n/4-historic-brass-studio",
"title": "4. Historic Brass Studio",
"content": "Vom 13. bis 16. März 2013 findet das 4. Historic Brass Studio Bremen an der Hochschule für Künste Bremen statt. Angeboten an den vier Tage authentische historische Spielpraxis für Trompete, Posaune, Zink und Horn:",
"img": "http:
//www.hfk-bremen.de/sites/default/files/imagecache/event_block_thumb_300w/media/historicbrassstudio_1.jpg",
"type": "concerts"
},
"2": {
"link": "http://www.hfk-bremen.de/t/konzerte/n/orgelkonzert-3",
"title": "Orgelkonzert",
"content": "Studierende der Orgeklassen von KMD Prof. Tilmann Benfer spielen die Choralbearbeitungen von Brahms und Kluge am 14.03.2013 im St. Petri Dom Bremen.",
"img": "http://www.hfk-bremen.de/sites/default/files/imagecache/content_start/imagegeneration/Orgelkonzert.png",
"type": "concerts"
},
"3": {
"link": "http://www.hfk-bremen.de/t/konzerte/n/musik-im-museum-6",
"title": "Musik im Museum",
"content": "Konzert mit Clovis Michon (Violoncello) aus der Klasse von Prof. Alexander Baillie am 14.03.2012 um 19.30 Uhr. Auf dem Programm stehen die Solo-Suiten von J.S. Bach No. 1-3, BWV 1007-1009",
"img": "http://www.hfk-bremen.de/sites/default/files/imagecache/event_block_thumb_300w/media/musikimmuseum_8.jpg",
"type": "concerts"
},
"4": { etc...
```

(You can visit this API link for a live preview if you have a JSON parser addon in your browser: http://hfkio.thisisasite.de/api/aktuelles)

I am using the GSON library which needs the objects to use as an example to parse the json. But i dont get the structure of this json, it looks to me like one big object containing various sub objects called "1,2,3..." which in turn contain 5 strings each. I am pretty new to JSON parsing and still learning, I don't fully get it how I am supposed to parse this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: what are you trying to parse out?

Comment: I am trying to get something like an array list of "news-item" objects, which all contain link title content img and type.. The amount of news-items are variable

Comment: So far as I can tell, it's JSON.  All legal JSON can be parsed into Java objects.  You don't need to know in advance what the format is, if you allow the parser to use its default generic objects -- an array object, and a "map" object, and a number object, and a string object, and a "NULL" object.  After parsing you can figure it out by querying the types of the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just parse it into a `Map`:

```
String json =
        "{\n" +
        "    \"1\": {\n" +
        "        \"link\": \"http://www.hfk-bremen.de/t/meisterkurse/n/4-historic-brass-studio\",\n" +
        "        \"title\": \"4. Historic Brass Studio\",\n" +
        "        \"content\": \"Vom 13. bis 16. März 2013 findet das 4. Historic Brass Studio Bremen an der Hochschule für Künste Bremen statt. Angeboten an den vier Tage authentische historische Spielpraxis für Trompete, Posaune, Zink und Horn:\",\n" +
        "        \"img\": \"http:\n" +
        "        //www.hfk-bremen.de/sites/default/files/imagecache/event_block_thumb_300w/media/historicbrassstudio_1.jpg\",\n" +
        "        \"type\": \"concerts\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    \"2\": {\n" +
        "        \"link\": \"http://www.hfk-bremen.de/t/konzerte/n/orgelkonzert-3\",\n" +
        "        \"title\": \"Orgelkonzert\",\n" +
        "        \"content\": \"Studierende der Orgeklassen von KMD Prof. Tilmann Benfer spielen die Choralbearbeitungen von Brahms und Kluge am 14.03.2013 im St. Petri Dom Bremen.\",\n" +
        "        \"img\": \"http://www.hfk-bremen.de/sites/default/files/imagecache/content_start/imagegeneration/Orgelkonzert.png\",\n" +
        "        \"type\": \"concerts\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    \"3\": {\n" +
        "        \"link\": \"http://www.hfk-bremen.de/t/konzerte/n/musik-im-museum-6\",\n" +
        "        \"title\": \"Musik im Museum\",\n" +
        "        \"content\": \"Konzert mit Clovis Michon (Violoncello) aus der Klasse von Prof. Alexander Baillie am 14.03.2012 um 19.30 Uhr. Auf dem Programm stehen die Solo-Suiten von J.S. Bach No. 1-3, BWV 1007-1009\",\n" +
        "        \"img\": \"http://www.hfk-bremen.de/sites/default/files/imagecache/event_block_thumb_300w/media/musikimmuseum_8.jpg\",\n" +
        "        \"type\": \"concerts\"\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "}";

Gson gson = new Gson();

Map map = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);

System.out.println(((Map)map.get("2")).get("title"));
```

which would print:

```
Orgelkonzert
```

Comment: This works, thank you for helping me learn a bit more about json!

Answer (score 2):

In JSON, the `{ }` brackets indicate an object.  A JSONObject is composed of key-value pairs, separated by commas.  In your case, the initial `{` indicates the start of the Object.  That Object consists of some number of key-value pairs where the keys are numbers (the "1, 2, 3..." that you're seeing) and the values are nested JSONObjects.  What you're seeing is exactly what you said, a single object with numbered sub-objects, because it's actually a JSONObject that contains numerous other JSONObjects.

Comment: Also check out an online json visualizer: http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm  This should help you visualize the data structures.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I used Bart Kiers answer now!